# How to determine a type of a scaling function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the code:

```
let scale = d3.scale.log();
//How to determine that 'scale' variable is a logarithmic scaling function?

scale = d3.scale.ordinal();
//In this case how to determine that 'scale' variable is an ordinal scaling function?
```

Is there some properties of a scale function or some methods that can help me?
I need this information in order to draw scale specific axises with HTML Canvas API.

Comment: Both scales are just functions and there is no property associated with scale functions to determine what kind it is. That said, even if there were a way to find out scale type, you should consider alternatives. What is your use case?

Comment: @Ankit
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726692/how-to-determine-a-type-of-a-scaling-function-dynamically/35727330?noredirect=1#comment59134027_35727330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to determine if it's an ordinal scale or not, you could use:

```
scale.hasOwnProperty("rangePoints")
```

Only ordinal scales have that method.

---

Alternate idea, if you are creating the scale, just keep track of it yourself:

```
scale = d3.scale.log();
scale.type = "log";
scale = d3.scale.linear();
scale.type = "linear";
```

Comment: I need to determine another function like linear, etc.

Comment: @KirillA.Khalitov, more straightforward method is to just keep track of it yourself.

Comment: I need more elegant code like `d3.axis` approach:
`var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)`
In this code I don't specify a scale type I just pass 'x' scaling function. How it works in `d3`?
I learn `d3` source code.

Comment: @KirillA.Khalitov Mark is correct here. D3's axis only "cares" about whether a scale is ordinal or not, and it determines this by checking if it has a `rangeBand()` method (see [d3 source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js#L9005)). Other than that, it doesn't matter to axis whether it's log or linear scale. We don't know what your code is doing with scale, but arguably, if d3 axis doesn't need to care what type of non-ordinal scale it is, then maybe your code can get around it too. Mark's suggestion of attaching a `type` to the scale is reasonable, although kind of fragile.